# Ajax data do not show in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have Allocate_classRoom **DB tabl**e where I want to show data using ajax

```js
 function departmentQuery()
  {
      var department = $('#department' ).val();

      if(department!=" ")
      {
          var urls = "{{ URL::to('roomAjax') }}";
          var request = $.ajax({
              url: urls+"/"+department,
              type: "GET",
              dataType: 'json'
          });
          request.done(function(data){
              var allRoom ="";
              for (var  i=0; i<data.length;i++)
              {
                 // room +="<option value=' " +data[i].id+ " ' >"+data[i].name+ "</option>";
              allRoom +=" <tr> " +
                            "<td>"+data[i].id+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+data[i].course_id+"</td>"+
                            /*"<td>"+ course->name+"</td>"+*/
                            "<td>"+data[i].Room_No+"</td>"+
                            "<td>"+data[i].date+data[i].start_time+data[i].end_time+"</td>"+

                          "</tr>";
              }
              $("#allRoom").html(allRoom);
          });
          request.fail(function(){
              alert('failed to get items for that department');
          });
      }else {
          alert('Select Department');
      }
  }
```

And I am uploading controller code

```html
public function ajaxRoom($id)
    {
        $allRoom = AllocateClassroom::where('department_id',$id)-
            >with('course')->get();
   

        return response()->json($allRoom);

    }
```

.Data return from the database but I could not show it my view table please I want your suggestion.

Comment: did you debug and see where it is failing. `debugger` and `console.log()` are your friends.

Comment: Actually, It does not show any error if  I see this using route then data show but I face problem to show it in my HTML table.